# How can I know if an IO is empty without reading it?

Tags: ruby, io

I have an `IO` object (like `$stdout`, `$stderr`). I can do `read.empty?` on it to see if it is empty, but is it possible to know if it is empty without reading it? I know that `File` has `size`, but `IO` does not.

**Edit**
Sorry if my question was not clear enough. I get these objects as return values from `Open3.popen3`. I want to see if anything was written to the standard error, for example. And I want to do it without reading it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a purpose of [IO::select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-select) method:

Updated example after question edited:

```
require 'open3'

select_timeout = Rational(1,10) # optional

Open3.popen3('ls /') do
  |stdin, stdout, stderr, w_thread|

  rdin, rdout, rderr = IO.select([stdin], [stdout], [stderr], select_timeout)
  if rdin
    p 'no data on standard input' unless rdin.member? stdin
    p 'no data on standard output' unless rdout.member? stdout
    p 'no data on standard error' unless rderr.member? stderr
  else
    p 'none of streams has data available'
  end

  retval = w_thread.value
end
# "no data on standard output"
# "no data on standard error"
```

Whereas only standard input contains data from spawned thread command `ls /`

Comment: @sawa It does not matter, `IO::select` can be used analogous. See example update.